# Trying to Install composer in usr/local/bin on Mac OS X 10.7.5

Tags: macos, composer-php

I am trying to get composer set up so I can work with the Laravel framework.

I successful edited my php.ini file, and are correct for installing Composer.  I changed directories to bin, by using the following command: `cd /bin`

Then, in bin, I used the following command to try to install Composer:

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=bin
```

but I get the following output:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
All setting correct for using Composer
The defined install dir (bin) does not exist
```

What could be the issue here?

I used echo $PATH to get the following output:

```
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin
```

so it appears that /usr/local/bin does exist.  I'm at a loss.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You shouldn't have to change directories before you run the installation command (and in any case, `/bin` is quite different from `/usr/local/bin`). Try this instead:

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin
```

Comment: Yes, it should. (Installation scripts like this are usually set up to take a path like `/usr/local/` because they're going to install things in `/usr/local/bin`, `/usr/local/lib`, and various other subdirectories. This particular script only installs something in `.../bin` and so it wants you to specify the `bin` directory directly.) Incidentally, the reason your original command didn't work was that the script thought you wanted to install the program into `/bin/bin`, which [almost certainly] doesn't exist.